# Redis CPU Consumption Issue

Tags: node.js, redis

We have a socket application in nodejs running on node cluster. We are using redis (node-redis) for store, and publish subcscribe.

The application creates 3 different instance: one for store, one for publish and one for subscribe. Everytime socket is connected, we are subscribing to a channel. This channel can have x clients connected to. Every socket connected can send message in the channel so publishing to all the sockets subscribed in the channel.

When we checked the number of channels used for subscribe can be around 15k-20k.. The number of socket connected to the application is more or less the same: meaning same traffic flow along the message flow.

We have different server for redis and node application. Everything works smooth but the issue is after 4-5 days the cpu consumes to 100% and gets stuck in redis server.  And if we restart the service everything works fine again with very minimal cpu consumption(less than 30%). We are saving data before restart so data is also same.

We are using redis v5.07. We cannot seem to find the cause of the cpu behavior so any insight would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Are you unsubscribing from channels? 
2. Does your data have TTL specified?

Comment: It seems something is not cleaning up, you should check the logs and there can be other things to interfering with it. It could be difficult to explain what exactly could cause such issues.

Comment: @Ayzrian 1. we are unsubscribing channels when the socket disconnects but there are few channels which we cannot as other user might be still subscribed to,. we are using single redis instance for subscribe so. 2. Yes, some of our data have TTL Specified.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara we have set log in warning mode but we dont' see any warnings/errors so far.